# Datatype mapping to MySQL in Rails ActiveRecord migrations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, types

Is there a data type in Rails ActiveRecord migrations that maps to tinyint in mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use :tinyint

but better check this out

http://craiccomputing.blogspot.com/2007/01/issues-with-tinyint-in-rails-table.html

hope this helps

cheers

sameera

Comment: Also I found that it was mentioned in the Rails API that any type supported by the database can be used. Only problem will be that the code will not be database independent.

Comment: @indika, true... coz rails will convert everything to pure sql. And in my personal opinion its highly unlikly u change the database later :D